# Combobox binded to Dictonary and retrieving the associated dictionary key

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dictionary, combobox

I have a `ComboBox`, and I have bound a `Dictionary` to it.  Here is the code:

```
<ComboBox Height="24" Name="comboBoxQuery" Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding QueryNames}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedQueryNames}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" Visibility="{Binding Path=ComboVisibility, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" />
```

Now, when I try to fetch the selected value, I get a string with key and value together. 
Ex: [1, "ABC"]

my view model code:

```
    public Dictionary<int, string> QueryNames 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return m_ReadOnlyQueryNames; 
        }
        set
        {
            m_queryNames = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("QueryNames");
        }
    }

    private string m_SelectedQueryNames;        

    public string SelectedQueryNames
    {
        get 
        {
            return m_SelectedQueryNames;
        }            
        set
        {
            if (m_SelectedQueryModule != value) <!-- value returns [1, "abc"]-->
            {
                m_SelectedQueryModule = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQueryNames");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `SelectedItem`, your property will get the whole object (in you case property will get dictionary element with key and value). If you want to get just key or just value, try using `SelectedValue`. But it depends on how you set up `SelectedValuePath`.

Regards,